# Other than the Obvious - Why do Oracle Objects become un-compiled

Tags: database, oracle, database-design, database-schema

Other than the Obvious - Why do Oracle Objects become invalid/un-compiled.  For example; we execute a release of a product with DML/DDL changes; we validate the Oracle Schema have No invalid objects.  We do not change any objects to cause objects to become uncompiled.  We are on oracle 10.2.0.4.0; and we created a script that runs every hour to compile invalid objects.  The environment is hosted; so I want to be well informed on Why this is happening.  Your thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

DML will not cause objects to go invalid, but DDL will. Objects go to an invalid state when a dependency is changed; a view, a package, a table, etc.

For example, if you add a column to a table, any dependent views or code (packages or standalone procedures/functions) will be marked as invalid. If running from SQL*Plus (i.e. connected directly) the next time you run one of those the view or package will re-compile and go back to a Valid state. Where it gets tricky, is when connecting via JDBC or (possibly) ODBC via connection pools. Using those methods, you usually need to create brand new sessions (or connection pools) to resolve the issue. Any session (or connection pool) still connected will still see those objects as Invalid and throw an error.

You should not need a script to recompile objects every hour. Ever. However, since this is hosted, perhaps your code has dependencies on objects outside of your schema. Most notably System objects (DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO, DBMS_ALERT, etc), but those would only very rarely change (usually with an upgrade), so it may be safe to rule that out. If you have dependencies on another application (schema) within that database, those objects may be changing and causing your dependent objects to be marked as Invalid.

Long-winded, but hopefully helpful.

Comment: Been lurking, finally decided to participate. Looks like fun!

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to speculate. A lot of errors come from changes to dependencies or permissions. To see the problem with a specific object, use this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM All_Errors
WHERE Name = '<invalid object name>'
  AND Owner = '<invalid object owner>'
```

The `<invalid object name>` and `<invalid object owner>` (meaning the schema) must be in uppercase unless the object name was defined using double-quotes and a non-uppercase name, for example `CREATE TABLE "BadDecision" AS ...`.

To see errors for all invalid objects, do this:

```
SELECT *
FROM All_Errors
WHERE (Owner, Name) IN (
  SELECT Owner, Object_Name
  FROM All_Objects
  WHERE status = 'INVALID')
```